# Please accept my request for an obsolete engineering theory

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, design

I am writing a thesis concerning government organization, and I would like to make the analogy that illustrates that law scholars are failing to seek practical solutions, because they are confined to an incomplete theory from two hundred a fifty years ago. And so, I need an engineering theory from about the same era that has been obsoleted by a recent improved engineering theory or law.

To let you in on the secret, the Three-part Separation Theory that formulates the American governing system is an incomplete theory that scholars, and everyone else, obviously overlook. The Three-part Separation Theory only defines the three parts - it does not define how to construct, or subdivide, those three parts. The Three-part Theory only prevents any one person from assuming a dictatorship, it does not prevent oligarchy (ideological alignment of representatives) contests for cotrol of the three parts. Which is the problem that we are enduring in American government.

Most people tend to believe that the founders did not expect political parties to emerge, but that is not true. There are at least three instances of the founders' writings that definitely suggest that they were well aware that political alignment was inevitable, it is just that they did not have a solution to dissipate the principles of the ideologies, which requires formulated subdivision of the three parts. Way too complex for them, because of the lack of information, man-power, and communications systems needed.

So, in an effort to illustrate my point about law scholars' ineptness, I would like a better description than just suggesting that we would still be using horses and carriages for transportation, outhouses for plumbing, and wood-fired stoves for cooking, if engineers were subservient to centuries-old ways of doing things.

What I would like is an easy-to-understand description of an obsolete theory that has been updated with a new theory that produces a readily understood technology that the law pinheads will recognize.

Comment: Check this link out. http://snst-hu.lzu.edu.cn/zhangyi/ndata/Obsolete_scientific_theories.html

Comment: your base assumption is about a political system, not a legal system.  Lots of people believe a parliamentary system is superior to the American system.  But this is a political problem not a legal one.

Comment: I understand the distinction, but law scholars are the practitioners that are more inclined to compose the directive systems necessary for organizing the government entities. We are certainly familiar with James Madison and others being described as the "architects of the government," and that is what I am trying to work the analogy further, because architects seemingly rely on engineering design for better construction. My analogy description for political science scholars is that they are at best critics and designers, they are not disposed to compose directive systems like a contract lawyer

Comment: While this is a subject I do find interesting, IMO it's kindof a stretch for the engineering board - especially as the audience you're going for are non-technical. Besides that, many of the best examples, from r13's link above, are probably too strong - implying that the people you're arguing against are particularly primitive in their thoughts - which doesn't sound like what you're going for.

Comment: To me, what you're asking for doesn't make sense for what you want it for. Being confined to specific theory doesn't really affect engineers using practical solutions. Engineers use practical solutions that seem to work, whether or not the engineer or even the physicist understands why it works. Physicists and mathematicians might be stuck in an out-dated theory that cannot explain why a method used by engineers seems to produce adequate results, but that doesn't stop the engineer from using them.

Comment: In addition to the list on the website referred to by @r13, there's also [eugenics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugenics).

Comment: This certainly applies to engineering systems governed by *regulations*, regardless of the underlying theory. An excellent example is the convoluted mess of the US domestic power system, which seems to have been designed to *maximize* the possibilities for failure and accidents  caused by bad workmanship and poor materials, rather than the reverse. Of course that also provides an excellent job protection scheme for approved electrical contractors, but I couldn't comment on whether that was part of the original intention!

Answer (score 1):

### I don't think this is a good analogy.

Engineering strictly speaking isn't about the underlying science principles.  People built arches before they understood the math behind it.  There are engineering problems that would be hard to solve without calculus, but people didn't solve them wrong before, they were just unsolved.

There are plenty of cases where engineers built solutions without understanding science first.  Liberty ships cracked in cold water before people understood cold embrittlement.  I'm sure tons of people were killed by steam plants over the early years.  But once failure occurs, the problems get solved rather quickly.

Now medicine did a ton of stuff wrong for centuries and killed a lot of people before they started applying science to medicine.  That would be a good place to go.  Bad science like Lysenkoism would also apply.  But engineering is as much empirical as scientific.  A bridge either works or it doesn't.

Comment: That seemingly answers my "problem."

Comment: @RonaldMartin Take a look at medical history starting with Galen. He dissected dogs and used them to make drawings of the human body because it was sacrilege to dissect humans at the time. Then when it became acceptable, for centuries medical schools would dissect human cadavers and do things like literally holding up the liver and say it had five-lobes according to Galen's dog dissections when it clearly did not. That's an example of hanging on to an outdated theory or framework and ignoring the practical.

Comment: "A bridge either works or it doesn't." - It might be more accurate to say "A bridge worked *until* it doesn't". There are plenty of examples, both ancient and modern.